# ManyToMany Relation in Template (Reverse LookUp)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to build my own client database and I just don't get the reverse lookup to work:

models.py

```
class PersonQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def employees(self):
        return self.filter(role='E')

class PersonManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return PersonQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)
    def employees(self):
        return self.get_queryset().employees()

class Person(models.Model):
    people = PersonManager()
    role = models.CharField(max_length=1,
    choices = (('C', _('Client')),('E', _('Employee'))))

class Organization(models.Model):
    employees = models.ManyToManyField(
        Employee,
        limit_choices_to=Q(role='E'),
        related_name='organization_employees',
        related_query_name='organization_employee',)
```

views.py

```
class PersonDetail(DetailView):
    model = Person
    template_name = 'clients/person_detail.html'
```

The Organization-Class relates over a ManyToMany-relation to several employees (Person-Class). The DetailView (template "person_detail.html") of every employee may now display the Organization, to which each employee belongs, I think about something like person.organization.name

I've tried this and many other solutions, but it has never worked so far, I just don't get why I'm stucked.

```
<ul>
{% for organization in people.organization_set.all %}
    {{ organization.name }}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Many many thanks for any help :)

Comment: Where is `people` coming from? The PersonDetail view that you've shown wouldn't add that variable. Do you mean `person` instead?

Comment: the people comes from the "Person-Class": people = PersonManager(). I use it to call the additional Employee-Class: class Employee(Person) like this: people.employee. But I think in this situation I should use person.organization_set.all. you're right. but that doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can call the many reverse lookup from a QuerySet, only an instance of the model.  You could use this instead:

```
<ul>
{% for person in people %}
    {% for organization in person.organization_set.all %}
        {{ organization.name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

You could also add a method to your `PeopleQuerySet` class to add this functionality.

```
class PersonQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def organization_set(self):
        return Organization.objects.filter(pk__in=self.values_list('organization', flat=True))
```

Comment: thanks, ARJMP for your suggestion. I think something in my code still is wrong. It's not working. Might there be an issue with the views.py PersonDetail class? I've tried to add a def get_context_data(self, **kwargs), but that also did no work. But I found a total different solution, adding a new def to the Person(models.Models) class and executing custom sql with connection.cursor() as cursor. Might not be that proper, but works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a different solution that worked, if I add a def to my Person(models.Model) class and execute custom sql.

models.py

```
class Person(models.Model):
     def get_organization(self):
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute('SELECT organization_id FROM clients_organization_employees WHERE employee_id = %s', [self.id])
            organization_id = cursor.fetchone()
            cursor.execute('SELECT name FROM clients_organization WHERE id = %s', [organization_id[0]])
            organization_name = cursor.fetchone()

        for x in organization_name:
            return x
```

In the template I now can call

```
{{ person.get_organization }}
```

and I always get the right organization, to which every employee belongs to.